# Unbind Access Project from source control

Tags: ms-access, version-control

I'm using Access 2007 and the project is bound to a version control system. Everytime I open the project locally, it uses the version control connection info automatically by default. And I don't know how and where to change the connection info.

I know I can change the connection info by using "Open from Source Control". However, I'm curiouse how I can change the connection if I open it locally. And where is the version control info stored in the Access project? And How can I unbind the prject from source control?

Thanks in advance.